# Python Dictionary Floats

Tags: python, dictionary, floating-point

I came across a strange behavior in Python (2.6.1) dictionaries:

The code I have is:

```
new_item = {'val': 1.4}
print new_item['val']
print new_item
```

And the result is:

```
1.4
{'val': 1.3999999999999999}
```

Why is this?  It happens with some numbers, but not others. For example:

- 0.1 becomes 0.1000...001
- 0.4 becomes 0.4000...002
- 0.7 becomes 0.6999...996
- 1.9 becomes 1.8888...889

Comment: Reading this: http://floating-point-gui.de/ may help you understand why.

Comment: I feel like this question is a duplicate...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Floating point inaccuracy examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100490/floating-point-inaccuracy-examples) - chosen because it was the duplicate cited [in this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909427/c-floating-point-precision)

Comment: It has nothing to do with the dictionary itself; it has to do with how the dictionary is formatted for display.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not Python-specific, the issue appears with every language that uses binary floating point (which is pretty much every mainstream language).

From the [Floating-Point Guide](http://floating-point-gui.de/basic/):

> Because internally, computers use a format (binary floating-point)
>   that cannot accurately represent a number like 0.1, 0.2 or 0.3 at all.
>
> When the code is compiled or interpreted, your “0.1” is already
>   rounded to the nearest number in that format, which results in a small
>   rounding error even before the calculation happens.

Some values *can* be exactly represented as binary fraction, and output formatting routines will often display the shortest number that is closer to the actual value than to any other floating-point number, which masks some of the rounding errors.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is related to floating point representations in binary, as others have pointed out.

But I thought you might want something that would help you solve your implied problem in Python.

It's unrelated to dictionaries, so if I were you, I would remove that tag.

If you can use a fixed-precision decimal number for your purposes, I would recommend you check out the [Python decimal module](http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html). From the page (emphaisis mine):

> - Decimal “is based on a floating-point model which was **designed with people in mind**, and necessarily has a paramount guiding principle – computers must provide an arithmetic that **works in the same way as the arithmetic that people learn at school**.” – excerpt from the decimal arithmetic specification.
> - **Decimal numbers can be represented exactly**. In contrast, numbers like 1.1 and 2.2 do not have an exact representations in binary floating point. End users typically would not expect 1.1 + 2.2 to display as 3.3000000000000003 as it does with binary floating point.
> - **The exactness carries over into arithmetic**. In decimal floating point, 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1 - 0.3 is exactly equal to zero. In binary floating point, the result is 5.5511151231257827e-017. While near to zero, the differences prevent reliable equality testing and differences can accumulate. For this reason, decimal is preferred in accounting applications which have strict equality invariants.