# C++: 0.3 instead of 0.29999999

Tags: c++

I need to use the value 0.3.
I am using float for this.
Now when I move the mouse of this variable in VS2010, it tells me 0.2999999 instead of 0.3.

But I would really need the 0.3.

Can anybody tell me how this can be done?
Thank you.

Comment: You can't, 0.3 doesn't have an exact representation in base 2. See [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: But in VB6 I can indeed assign a variable the value 0.3. And I need to produce the exact results in C++.

Comment: Also see this one about the very same value - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909427/c-floating-point-precision .

Comment: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) If you *really* need 0.3, you will need to use a different representation than floating-point types.

@MarkRansom LOL oops, I didn't see you post that link tharr ;)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985

Comment: @voidptr, no worries, I added it in an edit.

Comment: Added here since closed:Depending on the precision required, you could use integers and create a custom printing function.

For two decimal points, a `1` would actually be a `100` and so on. Then you can use only integer math and automatically round errors.

To print the numbers you could do something like this ( pseudocode ):

    string toString(int number) {
        std::string nString = standard_conversion_to_string(number/100);
        number = number % 100;
        if ( number != 0 ) {
            nString += ".";
            nString += covert_the_rest(number);
        }
    }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This depends on what you're trying to do. If you're trying to do something if the value is 0.3, you *could* try `if (x > 0.29 && x < 0.31)`, although this won't be completely accurate. But other than this the first comment is right, there is no way to get the value accurately.

I would comment before posting to check what is being done, but I lack the reputation to do so. If this turns out to be inaccurate, I will happily delete this answer, so please don't be too quick to downvote.

EDIT: you could also try storing the number as ten times larger and comparing for 3, but I wouldn't recommend this. Please provide details of why this needs to be done.

Comment: +1.  This is a good answer because you inferred the problem the user is facing and made a very good suggestion for how to solve it.  Yes, in general it's appropriate to ask the use case in a comment before answering but I feel this was appropriate.

Comment: ...but your edit is a worse idea.

Comment: @djechlin Thanks very much for the upvote, I now have enough reputation to post comments in future examples

Comment: @djechlin just added something indicating that the second suggestion is a bad idea. Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: Why suggest it at all then?

Comment: @djechlin He might feel that's a more appropriate way of doing it. While it might not seem like a good idea, it is still a possible solution, which the asker might prefer for whatever reason