# Rounding error in computing average

Tags: c++, floating-point, rounding, rounding-error

I have some problems with rounding errors in c++. If I have to compute the average of two floats `a` and `b`, then why is it better to do `a+0.5*(b-a)` than `(a+b)/2`? I can't understand why there should be any difference in the two ways of computing it.

Comment: Please show a [MCVE] as well as the expected and actual output.

Comment: Floating point numbers (i.e. `float` and `double`) are not like mathematical Real numbers (at best similar in certain limited ranges). To understand this better, these links may help: [SO: Floating point inaccuracy examples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2100490/7478597), [SO: C++ floating point precision](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2909427/7478597).

Comment: Sometime that is true, sometime not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your formula is correct in case if you are computing average of many numbers. In this case you can do the following:

μ<sub>n</sub> = 1/nΣx<sub>i</sub>

but here while adding 101st number you will need to add x<sub>101</sub> to μ<sub>100</sub>, where μ<sub>100</sub> could be pretty big compared to x<sub>101</sub>, and so you will lose some precision. To avoid this problem you can to like this:

μ<sub>101</sub> = μ<sub>100</sub> + 1/n(x<sub>101</sub> - μ<sub>100</sub>)

This formula is much better if you x<sub>i</sub> is of the same order of magnitude, as you avoid dealing with arithmetic operations between two big number and x<sub>i</sub>.

You might want to read article [Numerically stable computation of arithmetic means](https://diego.assencio.com/?index=c34d06f4f4de2375658ed41f70177d59)

Let's look into how numbers are represented in IEEE floating point. Consider C++ `float`:

Interval [1,2] goes with step 2<sup>-23</sup>, so you can represent numbers 1+n*2<sup>-23</sup>, where n belongs to {0, ..., 2<sup>23</sup>}.

Interval [2<sup>j</sup>, 2<sup>j+1</sup>] goes with like [1,2] but multiplied by 2<sup>j</sup>.

To, see how precision is lost you can run this program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
int main() {
    float d = pow(2,-23);
    std::cout << d << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::setprecision(8) << d + 1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::setprecision(8) << d + 2 << std::endl; // the precision has been lost
    system("pause");
}
```

The output is

> 1.19209e-07
>   1.0000001
>   2

Answer (score 3):

[Disclaimer: this answer assumes [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) format and semantics. Specifically, we assume that `float` is the IEEE 754 binary32 format, that we're using the default round-ties-to-even rounding mode, and that intermediate expressions are not computed with extended precision - e.g., because [`FLT_EVAL_METHOD`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/climits/FLT_EVAL_METHOD) is `0`.]

Here's one possible reason to prefer `a + 0.5 * (b-a)`: *if* `a` and `b` are very large and have the same sign, then the intermediate quantity `a + b` in the expression `0.5 * (a + b)` might overflow, giving either an infinite result or a floating-point exception. In contrast, `a + 0.5 * (b - a)` will not overflow in that situation.

However, that small advantage should be weighed against the following:

- `a + 0.5 * (b - a)` requires three floating-point operations; `0.5 * (a + b)` requires only two.
- in cases where `a + b` does *not* overflow, `0.5 * (a + b)` always provides a correctly-rounded answer: that is, it gives the *best possible* approximation to the actual mean, given the representability constraints of the target type. (That's not *entirely* obvious, but not hard to prove: either `a + b` is greater in magnitude than twice the smallest normal, in which case the sum is correctly rounded and the multiplication by `0.5` is exact, or `a + b` is itself computed exactly, and then the multiplication by `0.5` is correctly rounded. Either way, at most one of the two arithmetic operations can introduce an error.) But `a + 0.5 * (b - a)` will *not* always give a correctly-rounded mean, and in fact can be many millions of ulps in error. Consider the case where `a = -1.0` and `b = 1.0 + 2^-23`. Then `a + 0.5 * (b - a)` gives `0.0`. The correct mean is `2^-24`.
- the expression `a + 0.5 * (b - a)` can *also* overflow, if `a` and `b` are very large with *opposite* signs rather than the same sign. In that situation, `0.5 * (a + b)` will not overflow.
- `a + 0.5 * (b - a)` is (very slightly) less readable than `0.5 * (a + b)`; it requires a moment's more thought on the part of the reader to figure out what it's doing.

Given the above, it's hard to support a general recommendation that `a + 0.5 * (b - a)` should be used in preference to `0.5 * (a + b)`.